# How do I access a custom reverse model manager in a template?

Tags: python, django

Given the following models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CustomQuerySet1(models.QuerySet):
    def some_method(self):
        return 'custom queryset 1'

class CustomQuerySet2(models.QuerySet):
    def some_method(self):
        return 'custom queryset 2'

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = models.Manager()
    custom1 = CustomQuerySet1.as_manager()
    custom2 = CustomQuerySet2.as_manager()
```

In my REPL I can access the custom related managers like so:

```
>>> author = Author.objects.create(name='John')
>>> book = Book.objects.create(author=author, title='Hello')
>>> author.books(manager='custom1').some_method()
   'custom queryset 1'
>>> author.books(manager='custom2').some_method()
   'custom queryset 2'
```

And in our templates we normally access related objects via the default manager like so:

```
{% for book in author.books.all %}
    {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

We obviously aren't allowed to make function calls and pass in parameters within templates:

```
{% for book in author.books(manager='custom1').some_method %}
{% endfor %}
```

So is there a native way to access these custom related model managers in our templates I'm not aware of? Was something like this never intended? Any outside the box solutions?

Edit:
In case there was some confusion within the comments, I wasn't suggesting the following:

```
def some_view(request):
    context = {}
    template = 'my_template.html'
    context['author'] = Author
    return render(request, template, context)
```

and then calling `author.objects.all` but instead:

```
def some_view(request):
    context = {}
    template = 'my_template.html'
    author = Author.objects.get(name='John')
    context['author'] = author
    return render(request, template, context)
```

and then accessing `author.books.custom1.some_method`. Note the `related_name` on `author` defined on the `Book` model.

Comment: I don't think it's possible atm. What you can do though is create the queryset in the view and pass it to the template. It's actually the preferred way, as conceptually the template should not trigger queries.

Comment: From what I've seen I don't think it's possible either. Given querysets are lazy don't templates trigger queries all the time? Wouldn't preventing queries in templates fall to something like `select_related` and `prefetch_related`?

Comment: The point is the view was responsible for creating it, not the template. It is true that they are lazy so template evaluation will trigger them, but that's an implementation detail. For instance, the template may loop on `all_books`, but it is up to the view to define what `all_books` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

There is none and I think it won't (because it shouldn't).
Template is a place where data is finally presented, so it should all be prepared and template markup only used to present it in a convenient way.

However, it can be a nice idea for a template filter.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on why it shouldn't? What's the difference between calling `author.books.all` and `author.books(manager='custom1').custom_method` in the template if they both present data? Additionally, we are allowed to write custom methods on the default model manager and access them in the template `author.books.i_only_want_a_subset_of_this_authors_books`

Comment: You should not call `author.books.all` in the template either. The fact that it works does not means it's right. Check out how Django's generic views work, they are really well designed. At no point they give a model or a manager to the template.

Comment: I've never heard this advice. Even the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system) suggests it.

Comment: It's because of the layer design. Presentation layer should present, not prepare the data.

Comment: Generic views absolutely [pass in a model](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/). See `SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data`.

Comment: But they have `get_queryset` method, where you can do this magic like picking apriopriate manager.

Comment: Anyway guys, we are just arguing if something that is not now possible should be possible. I could undertsand this in a PR comments, but here it is just pointless. Let's call it a tie and think about how to solve this situation with currently available tools.

Comment: @RadosławGanczarek Agreed. I like the idea of determining the manager within `get_queryset`, I'll test this out. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottWoodall Just to make myself clear, by model, I meant the model class (`Book`), not the model instance. That is, it does not allow the template to do `{% for book in Book.objects.all %}`. I'm sorry that was confusing the way I wrote it. It passes either a piece of data (model instance), or a list of pieces of data (which may be an actual list of model instances or a queryset, the template should not care).

Comment: @spectras Thumbs up. I don't think anyone is/was suggesting passing in the model class and iterating over that.